# MediaElement.Stop doesn't work when playing a live streaming source in windows store app

Tags: mediaelement, live-streaming, windows-store, windows-store-apps

I want to make a Windows Store App play a live-streaming source. The source plays fine but I can't stop the source from playing once it has begun. When I call Stop() on the instance of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement nothing happens.

Below is my code:

```
public MainPage(){
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.mediaplayer.AutoPlay = true;
    this.mediaplayer.Source = new Uri("mms://somedomain/mylive");
}
...
void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //I can reach here when I set a breakpoint
    this.mediaplayer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: If you can provide a jsfiddle from here. Usualy resolves things alot faster. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same problem... and was able to solve it by calling `MediaElement.Pause()` instead.